# Words meaning “medical checkup”

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I’ve come across a few terms for medical examination:

身体{しんたい}検査{けんさ}

健康{けんこう}診断{しんだん}

検診{けんしん}

Which word should one use for an annual health checkup?

Are the words above any different in their meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is most probably 健康診断. It refers to a general health check-up.

検診 is a more specific check-up that aims to detect a particular disease, such as cancer as in the case of がん検診. Some 検診 may be included in 健康診断.

身体検査 has some overlap with 健康診断 but its focus is more on body measurement and simple fitness test than medical examination. When I hear this word, I think of those conducted on kids in schools.