Is there a different in context or meaning between "健康診断" and "身体検査" when referring to a medical checkup?
Are they synonyms or is there specific context for each use? Do they both mean different types of medical examinations?

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91040/43676

健康診断 (often shortened to 健診) refers to medical checkup/screening programs typically conducted annually. In particular, 人間ドック (literally "human dock") is a type of 健康診断 where your body is thoroughly checked over two days or so. Although expensive, it has a certain popularity.
身体検査 broadly refers to a check performed on someone's body, but it is not commonly used in medical contexts anymore. Today, it is used in situations such as:

Tests conducted to verify if athletes, military personnel, pilots, etc., meet the required physical standards before starting their jobs.
Inspections involving physical contact with the body to check for security or clothing regulation compliance.

"Physical examination" in medical contexts (like a tendon reflex test) is normally called 診察, although 身体検査 might be used occasionally.

In criminal procedure law, 身体検査 means medical and security check. 身体検査 also refers to a background check, which involves investigating the conduct, character, and relationships of a person being considered for a position. It is also used in the politics when appointing ministers.

@ysaku A part of what you've described seems to be 身辺調査 rather than 身体検査 to me.

naruto Refer to the following link https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%e8%ba%ab%e4%bd%93%e6%a4%9c%e6%9f%bb/

@ysaku Thanks. I just confirmed another dictionary (明鏡) says 〔俗〕人を登用・採用する際に、交友関係や素行などを調べること。身辺調査。 And out of the 109 instances of 身体検査 on BCCWJ, 5 were actually 身辺調査 (e.g., "内閣の身体検査が甘かった"). I feel this is a minor, slangy and derivative meaning, though.

naruto Thank you. 身体検査 in the sense of a background check is slang. But news media often use this word in political contexts. Try searching Google News with the keywords 身体検査 and 閣僚. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%BA%AB%E4%BD%93%E6%A4%9C%E6%9F%BB%22+%22%E9%96%A3%E5%83%9A%22&tbm=nws
